# PHP header location redirect issue

Tags: php, header, http-headers

When I try to redirect page using the `header('Location: ...')` function it is appending the redirect URL to current pages URL instead.

For Example, my current page is `http://www.example1.com`.
I have created a simple file called `test.php` with the code below in it:

```
header('Location: http://www.example2.com');
```

However it is currently redirecting the page to `http://www.example1.com/http://www.example2.com` instead of `http://www.example2.com`.

Any suggestion what should be the issue?
This issue has arisen after moving the site to a new server. I am running the site by doing host entry.

Comment: post your test.php with the header location pls.

Comment: Show some code, then we can help. [How to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: <?php  header('Location: http://www.example2.com'); ?> This is the code in my index.php of "http://www.example1.com/" and when I run http://www.example1.com/index.php it is redirecting to http://www.example1.com/http://www.example2.com/

Comment: i thins its related to the server configuration, try 
   flag
 
<?php header('Location: http://example2.com'); ?> with http:// and not with www.

Comment: Hi Volkinc, Thanks. Yes it worked after I change it without www.  Do you know what server configuration I need to do so it will work with www also.